# Disable href property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I want to disable the `a` link from refreshing the page (i.e. going to the href link). But I want to the url to be modified, as per the `href` value.

Currently, I am trying this

```
$('.advertPP').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = link.attr("href");
});
```

HTML Link

```
<a href="products?id=<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="advertPP">Link</a>
```

Since both are on the same page, so I don't want the page to be refreshed but i want the url to be modified as in the href value.

Comment: So, you want to replace the behavior of a link with the behavior of a link?

Comment: yes, i want to change the url without refreshing

Comment: Setting the `location.href` will cause a page reload.

Comment: So can you provide a alternative ?

Comment: Sure - use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: @acdcjunior , shuld i replace "link.attr()" with "link.data("href");" ?

Comment: @user210068 No, no, keep using `link.attr("href")`, nevermind what I said (it will only make things more confusing, I apologize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of(logical) errors.

```
$('.advertPP').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = this.href; //or $(this).attr("href"), is the same thing, jQuery is not needed in this case
});
```

Maybe you want your page to change contents without refreshing, so you need **AJAX**, here is an example:

```
$('.advertPP').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(data) {
            //if the loaded page is a full html page, replace the HTML with the data you requested
            $("body").html(data); //make sure your data has only body contents, either you can replace the full HTML even if it is a bad practice $("html").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what shuld i replace with data, didn't get it ?

Comment: It depends on what is returned from the ajax request. If it is a complete HTML page, including `<html>` and `<head>` tags you can use `$("html").html(data)` instead of `$("body").html(data)`, even if it is not a good practice

Comment: your code works, the only problem is that the id which i need, get returned after 2 clicks, meaning that the id is updated when i click twice, else it show the previous one

Comment: How much time do you wait before clicking the second time? Ajax is Asynchronous, so the page will go on in being executed but and the callback will be called when the data is completely loaded. Try to click one time and wait some seconds, it should work. What do you mean when you say "id"?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on a lot of things, starting from your connection speed up to server response speed. So the real answer is no, it is not possible(at least without a lot of work)

Comment: It takes approx 2 seconds to load on localhost, is it fine or too slow?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, there are too much thing that I don't know. If your response is a page of 3 chars, then it is very much. If it is a page of 1GB(yeah, I'm kidding obviously) it is a *very good* timing. Is it clear to you that in this case I cannot help you? :P

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are not passing `event` object to your function. You should pass the object like this:

```
$('.advertPP').click(function(event) {
                            //^^^^^ pass the event object
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("href", "http://...");
});
```

Comment: $("link") will point to what? Maybe you wanted to write $(this) ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's my mistake there. Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Uhm, I don't really understand your code, even if it is now correct. `$(this).attr("href", "...");` will only change the attribute of the link, it won't change/reload the page

Comment: I thot the OP wanted to change `href` attribute only but prevent a page reload **only**.

Comment: There was a `location.href` set, so I think he wanted to change the page :P

Comment: @LightStyle: no, he wants not.

Comment: Yet, he/she doesn't explicitly specify it. Even the title of the question is not pointing in that direction. Maybe I'm wrong, but this is what I'm seeing here

Comment: @Cranio it is not sure, because in the question he said a thing, then he said something else in the comments... It is not completely clear what is being asked here, anyway I think he wanted an ajax request(see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether document.URL and $(this).attr('href') are same then set new url and return false.
If both are different them redirect to the page.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var currentUrl = document.URL
    if ($(this).attr('href') == currentUrl) {
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
        return false;
    }
})
```